# django rest api framework "list" obj has no attribute values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I trying to pass some files through djangorest framework and while trying to do so, I am facing error

> 'list' object has no attribute 'name'

my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from restfilesupload.serializers import FileSerializer


class FileUploadViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def create(self, request):

        serializer_class = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if 'file' not in request.FILES or not serializer_class.is_valid():
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.getlist("file"))
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)


    def handle_uploaded_file(f):
      with open(f.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['pk' , 'file']
```

my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers


class FileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    file = serializers.FileField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False)
```

My error :

[image]

Here is the github repo for the project ..

[github](https://github.com/MiteshChakma/django-apiTest)

where currently I can upload single file just fine but the problem arises while trying to upload multiple images

Comment: Please add the full error.

Comment: uploaded and updated my error

Comment: you are passing a list to a function and trying to get an attribute called name so that's why you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

From official Django 3.1 documentation: [HttpRequest.FILES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES)

> A dictionary-like object containing all uploaded files. Each key in FILES is the name from the . Each value in FILES is an UploadedFile.

From official Django 3.1 documentation: [QueryDict.getlist(key, default=None)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES)

> Returns a list of the data with the requested key. Returns an empty list if the key doesn’t exist and default is None. It’s guaranteed to return a list unless the default value provided isn’t a list.

Your problem is in this line:

`handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.getlist("file"))`

Try

`handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])`